# HTTPModule handle page content

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, httphandler, httpmodule

I am trying to create a virtual file. For example, I have a component that gets a CMS page from the DB with a given ID. Now I have a url like `/hello/world/`, and I want to parse the page `/hello/world/` into my `ContentPlaceHolder` in the `MasterPage`.

In the `IHttpModule` I am able to catch the URL, and I can rewrite it to a fysical file.

That was only step 1, now I need to load a virtuale page that does not exists. Therefore I don't think that I can use `app.Context.RewritePath()` because that needs a fysical file on the server.

Q: Is there any way to render my CMS page component in a `ContentPlaceHolder` in a `Masterpage`? Without having a fysical file?

I do have an idea about combining the IHttpModule and rewrite the file to a `.cmspage` extension and then using a `IHttpHandler` to catch that file extension and load my component, but that does look like not done?

Answer (score 0):

When you call an ASP.NET page, IIS use default `VirtualFileProvider` to load the file from IO and if the file is not located in the path, exception will be raised. Good news is that you can implement your custom provider and add the  provider. So, if the file doesn't exists in IO, you can load your own content from anywhere you want (load from DB, other files,...).

You can use it to load virtual ascx, aspx, and all ASP.NET file extentions.

First of all you need to write your custom `VirtualFile` and `VirtualPathProvider`. Then register the  provider using `HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider` in `Global.asax`.

Here is a good implementation to get the file content (which does not exists) from Assembly Resources: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16803/Embedded-UserControls-Revisited